# How to create a custom article type in octopress?

Tags: octopress

There are 2 different article types: post(blog) and page in Octopress. What if I like to creat another custom article type (ex, project) with different article template and index page? Just like we can have on Drupal's node system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use different stylesheet.